# Connectors do not appear automatically in easy custom labelling

Tags: qgis, labeling, qgis-3

I'm using the easy custom labelling plugin in QGIS 3. When I move a label away from its associated polygon a connector does not automatically appear as in QGIS 2.18. How do I get connectors to appear in QGIS 3?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Also getting a python error when I move the labels: AttributeError: 'QgsGeometry' object has no attribute 'exportToWkt' . Perhaps the two are related?

Comment: When I generate the layer it also seems to ignore the Field that you select for it to use as its labelling Field, and defaults to one of the new fields 'Lblfld', which it auto-populates with "1'. In previous versions it would auto-populate this with your chosen field. Again, perhaps a related issue?