# Changing label anchor point in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, labeling, leader-line, anchor-point

Based on my previous question, answered here [Can not get the connecting line to align with label in desired place in QGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285102/can-not-get-the-connecting-line-to-align-with-label-in-desired-place-in-qgis-3). Now I have a new issue.

As can be seen in the image included, I have manged to get leaders from my points to my labels. The problem is, at the label they are anchoring to the bottom left hand corner of the label, which for this image just does not look right. My preference is to make the leader line anchor to the top left hand corner of the label text or the centre of the label, again at the top of the label.

I have tried to alter the horizontal (to Centre) and vertical (to Half) as suggested in a similar question posed by someone else but this has not worked.

How can I change the anchor point to either of the above options?

[image: ][1]]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, using `Highlight Pinned Labels and Diagrams` button, double-click on a label and call up `Label Properties` dialogue. There is `Horizontal alignment` and `Vertical alignment` pull-down menu. Select desired one.

[image]

This has to be done on each label one by one...

Comment: Thanks Kazuhito, again! Excellent advice works perfectly.