# Using Label Leader line in QGIS?

Tags: labeling, qgis-3, leader-line

I am using QGIS 3.2.

I am trying and trying to get a line from my points to my labels! I have not moved the labels manually, but they are offset using the "offset from point" choice for placement. 
There seems to be a new field in the attribute table called "auxiliary_storage_labeling_offsetquad". I activated the little data defined box and chose the aux storage for the Field Type for everything relevant - see below (maybe more than needed?)

[image]

I am trying to use the Geometry Generator and have tried *many* slight variations in the formula. I tried creating new fields of x and y in my table and defining the labels with those, as suggested in some tutorials (i think for older versions). Heres my latest attempt as an example

[image]

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and don't know what else to try.

Comment: Perhaps this thread will help https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285102/qgis-3-line-connecting-point-to-label-issue-can-not-get-line-to-align-with-lab/

Comment: Thanks I have looked at that thread and all relevant ones i could find. To me it looks like i am following all the steps correctly but it's not working still. Is there something about what type of layer, or project properties, or i don't know what that could be preventing lines from appearing?

Comment: On 3.6 and I can't get lines to show up either. I just tried @Kazuhito 's suggest too.

Answer (score 2):

There were a couple of changes made to `Easy Custom Labeling` tool.

1. associated field names for X, Y coordinates of labels have changed to "LblX" and "LblY".
2. the output comes with Line geometries.

So, please try `make_line(start_point($geometry), make_point("LblX", "LblY"))` instead.

[image]